# dnd-drop and dnd-moved not working together

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, drag

I'm using Angular drag and drop list for a pipeline system. I found [this link](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple). I'm using the simple drop, see my code.

```
<div class="col-md-2" dnd-list="val" ng-repeat="(key,val) in LeadList" dnd-drop="drop($index,key,val,item)">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h6 class="panel-title">{{key}}</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body p-5" style="background:#F5F8FA">
            <ul class="media-list">
                <li class="media bg-white p-5" ng-repeat="item in val" dnd-draggable="item"
                    dnd-moved="val.splice($index, 1)"
                    dnd-effect-allowed="move" style="border-radius: .1875rem; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(45,62,80,.12);">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <table class="table table-borderless">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="no-padding p-5">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <div class="media-heading">
                                            <b>{{item.Name}}</b><br />
                                            {{item.Mobile}}<br />
                                            {{item.Employee}}
                                            @*<img src="assets/images/demo/users/face24.jpg" class="img-circle img-xs" alt="">*@
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="no-padding">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-price-tags"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-notebook"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-task"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-folder-open2"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```